# Set desired element to 1, the rest 0

Tags: python, list

My goal is to set only the desired elements of the my_list to `1` and the rest to `0`.
Expected output is [1,0,1]. Is there a simply way without using explicit for loop?

```py
my_list = [0.2, -0.5, 0.1]
set_to_one = [0, 2]  # I want to set 0 th, 2nd element to 1, the rest 0
```

Expected result is `[1,0,1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `starmap` from `itertools` you can unpack the tuples generated by `enumerate` and then classify.

```
import itertools as it

to_ones = [0, 2]

my_list = [0.2, -0.5, 0.1]

iter_ = it.starmap(lambda i, _:1 if i in to_ones else 0, enumerate(my_list))

print(list(iter_))
```

**Remark**: since the output list does not depends on its elements but only on its length, the iterator passed to `starmap` is a bit an "overkill". [I readapted my original approach which used a list comprehension]

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps build a list of zeros, then run a loop setting the desired elements to one.

```
my_list = [0] * len(my_list)
for i in set_to_one:
    my_list[i] = 1
```

Result:

```
>>> my_list
[1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Wow Raymond Hettinger! After creation of a list of zeroes, maybe `list(map(lambda x: my_list.__setitem__(x, 1), set_to_one))` can do the job with *implicit* `for` loop :D